# "Differences in values" - use "is" or "are"?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

> Differences in values **are/is** not necessarily the **source/sources** of conflicts

Which word should I choose in each pair of words separated by "/"?

Comment: This is a good grammar question, one that deals with subject-verb agreement in a copular-like clause. :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is as follows:

'Differences in values are not necessarily the source of conflicts'.

Please look at a couple of sentences of this type as follows:

1- Oranges are a source of vitamin "C".

2- oil, water, coal, natural gas and nuclear are sources of electricity.

I think when we refer to a group of related things (family), we use the singular source and when we refer to groups of different related things, we use the plural sources.

Comment: To be clear, the plural that "are" agrees with is "differences" rather than "values" in this sentence.

Comment: Jason Patterson, I know "are" agrees with differences, not values. Another example: His antics are a source of much enjoyment (The Free Dictionary)!

Comment: I assumed you did.  :)  It was a comment to try to clarify which plural noun was the subject for pxc3110.

Answer (score 0):

> Differences in values are not necessarily the sources of **conflict**.

Conflict should be singular here, simply because there isn't any reason to make it plural. The verb tense is plural, because the base subject is **differences** (*not* values, or anything else). Likewise, the second word should be **sources** because "differences" is plural.

Comment: But singular "source" could also work, given an apt context. Husband/wife, say, with differences in values on child-rearing, might argue over how to deal with a particular infraction by their child. The differences in their values would be a source of conflict.